# Is there a way to modify a constraint in a Gurobi Optimizer to help me Modell the Workforce Balance

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am currently working on a Gurobi model that should help me with a manpower optimization problem. Currently I am stuck with the workforce balance. The Model contains 3 Sets. First the periods in months, then the respective salary stage ranging from 1 to 27. And lastly the skill of the worker( 1 and 2). My problem now is the model should decide when the best time is to train a worker from skill 1 to skill 2 depending on demand satisfaction for skill 2. The worker then stays in skill 2 and climbs the salary stages there. The problem I face is that if the worker is in salary stage (27-17) of skill 1 he has to be trained to work in salary stage 7 of skill 2. if he is in stage (16-15) he will be transferred to stage 6. And stage 14 will be transferred to stage 5 until stage 10 where all later stages will be transferred to stage 1 of skill 2.

Currently my constraint looks like this

```
for t in months:
    for step in range(27, 0, -1):
      manpower.addConstr(Wp["1", t, step] == Wp["1", t-1, step] + H["1", t, step] - H["2",   t, step])
```

where W is the Workforce in month t at the corresponding step of the salary stage. H is the hiring for the respective skill. Also you can Hire someone externally but only in skill 1.
manpower.addConstrs(

```
H[("1", t, step)] == 0
    for step in salary_steps[2:] for t in months)
```

Also I limited to hiring so it only hires for skill1 in the first step

here is additional code

```
for t in months:
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 7)] == U[t, 17] + U[t, 18])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 6)] == U[t, 16] + U[t, 15])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 5)] == U[t, 14])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 4)] == U[t, 13])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 3)] == U[t, 12])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 2)] == U[t, 11])
    manpower.addConstr(H[("2", t, 1)] == U[t, 11] + U[t, 10] + U[t, 9] + U[t, 8] +
                       U[t, 7] + U[t, 6] + U[t, 5] + U[t, 4] + U[t, 3] + U[t, 2] + U[t, 1])

for t in months:
    for step in range(27, 0, -1):
        if t == 1:
            manpower.addConstr(Wp["1", 1, step] == WC["1", step] + H["1", t, step] - U[t, step] + Leavers_and_Joiners["1", t, step])
        else:
            manpower.addConstr(Wp["1", t, step] == Wp["1", t-1, step] + H["1", t, step] - U[t, step] + Leavers_and_Joiners["1", t, step])
```

Now it takes the workers from the right section. But still it doesn't use it from the highest step. It should work down from the highest step and use the available workers there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a code snippet or an Idea how to code the Workforce Balance constraint. This constraint is integrated in my Model. My Model should calculate the optimal Workforce for a company. This company has two skillsets required. The goal is to reduce cost and give the optimal time when to hire somebody or train somebody from skill 1 to skill 2. Unfortunately I don't know how to tell the model how to correctly train somebody so that the worker is transferred to the right salary stage. And I need help with the constraint or the coding on how to implement this constraint

Comment: Should I post the whole code? maybe this can make it clearer?